# Construct and render backbone view with respect to elements clicked

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Hi I'm Running into a problem with backbone js

I have a comment view

```
class window.CommentView extends Backbone.View
  el: $('.comment')
  initialize: ->
    @$el.show()
  events:
    "click": "renderCommentBoxView"

  renderCommentBoxView: ->
    @commentBoxView = new CommentBoxView
      id: this.$('.comment')['context']['activeElement']['id']
      model: new Item
      el: @el
```

And A comments Box View

```
 class window.CommentBoxView extends Backbone.View
   el: $('.commentBoxMain')

   events:
     "click.comment": "showCommentBox"
     "click document": "stopEvent"
     "click .login_button": "submitComment"
   initialize: ->
     @showCommentBox()

   stopEvent: (event) ->
     event.stopPropagation()

  showCommentBox: ->
     $(@el).append('<textarea class=\'commentBox\'></textarea><br/><input type=\'button\' class=\'login_button\' name=\'Add a comment\' value=\'Add a comment\'><span class=\'loading\' style=\'display: none;\'>Loading...</span>')
```

Now, there are multiple items on which a user can comment. So when ever the comment button is clicked I render a new view called CommentBoxView defining the element and the model

The problem is that I cant get the current clicked element to which the view should be bound.

My sample HTML  would look like this:

```
   <div id="item_1">
     <a class="comment" href='javascript:void(0)'>Comment</a>
     <div class="commentMainBox"></div>
   </div>
  <div id="item_2">
    <a class="comment" href='javascript:void(0)'>Comment</a>
    <div class="commentMainBox"></div>
  </div>
```

When ever the comment link is clicked I construct the html and dump in the commentMainBox.
But the problem is the element clicked is always the first element with class comment on my page. How can I get the current clicked element so as to render the content in the correct div.

Also the element for CommentBoxView should be `el: $('.commentBoxMain')` but if I assign this then I get nothing rendered in the view but when I initialize to `el: $('.comment')`, I see the comment box but then it renders always under the first comment no matter which one was clicked.

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be passing `@el` from the `CommentView` to the `CommentBoxView` that it instantiates; nor is declaring `el: $('.commentBoxMain')` in the `CommentBoxView` class going to work. As the Backbone.js docs say:

> If you'd like to create a view that references an element already in the DOM, pass in the element as an option: `new View({el: existingElement})`

Otherwise, the `View` tries to create a new element. So what you want to do is:

```
@commentBoxView = new CommentBoxView
  model: new Item
  el: @$('.commentMainBox')
```

This will find the `commentMainBox` element that's within the Comment view (since `@$` is scoped within its element) and provide that as the `CommentBoxView`'s element.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it doesn't work. Also the commentMainBox isn't within the commentView. I first thought of creating the commentMainBox view dynamically when the comment linked is clicked but later I thought It would be good if I define the commentBox view just below the comment link. I've done similar things in other parts of the projects and they do work but here the case is a little different. Here I need to render the same view multiple times in multiple places. And the biggest problem i face here is that i dont get the current clicked element.

Comment: Also, At least when I click the comment link, It should give me the current element instead it gives me the first element with class = 'comment'. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Defining el: $('.commentBoxMain') to refer to an existing element in the DOM works fine for me. Though in that case I would use an ID instead of class, because your element is (and should be) unique.